# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable in python

Tags: sorting, python-3.7, nonetype

```
#i'm just testing it 

lst=[3, 2, 4, 5,1]

print([i for i in lst if i % 2 != 0].sort()[0])

#i haven't tried any thing        

#I expect the output 1
```

Comment: `#i haven't tried any thing` -- I suggest that you do: remove the `[0]` and see what type the expression has (you can use `type` for that or just `print`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort()` sorts a list in place and returns `None`. Looks like you meant to use `sorted` instead:

```
print(sorted([i for i in lst if i % 2 != 0])[0])
```

Note, however, there's no need to sort the list if you just take its first element. You could use `min` instead for the same result with a better performance (O(n) instead of O(nlog(n)):

```
print(min([i for i in lst if i % 2 != 0]))
```

Comment: Or use sorted like this heheheh

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is, when you run the 'sort' function on a list, this function updates the list and returns void. So you really are trying to call a index on a NoneType object.

The best way to solve this problem is setting the filter to a variable, run the sort on this var and after this, print the value that you want to.

Ex:

```py
l = [i for i in lst if i % 2 != 0]

l.sort()

print(l[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

sort() is modifying method and returns None

This one works:

```
lst=[3, 2, 4, 5,1]
odds = [i for i in lst if i % 2 != 0]
ods.sort()
print(ods[0])
```